# Why do different SE sites allow different syntax in text editors?

Tags: support, comments, syntax-highlighting

In particular, why can I type LaTeX syntax (e.g. $\sin(x)$) when commenting on Math.SE and not on TeX.SE?

I think this is a design choice, but I don't really understand why not unify styles. What if one user (not me!) has dozens accounts on SE? Doesn't it risk to get a real mess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathJax is an expensive file to load, and the rendering is also pretty expensive (it's all client side).

That means that for sites that don't *need* LaTeX support, it's not turned on.

As for the exact details of why the TeX site doesn't have it, I'm guessing that it's because they need to be able to see raw input more often than they need to see the results. As [Mad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151385/mad-scientist) also points out, the MathJax library that SE uses is not exactly Tex or LaTeX so it could cause confusion on the TeX site.

Comment: MathJax is also not exactly TeX or LaTeX, there are differences which could lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: Indeed, we [very specifically _do not_ want MathJaX enabled on the TeX site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181): it was enabled very early on and we got it turned off. MathJaX is for making a small subset of TeX-like math mode input look 'nice' inside a browser, while the TeX site is _not_ a maths site and we _need_ to see what TeX itself does with things :-)